# Force component to redraw it's focus

Tags: apache-flex, focus, redraw

I'm having one more "How do I" question :)
Suppose I have a component and want to change it's focus color at runtime. Here's an example for you (I've excluded any buttons and such to prevent component from losing it's focus, cause in that case it changes it's color perfectly):

```
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
                creationComplete="init()">
    <mx:Script><![CDATA[    
        private function init():void {
            //putting focus inside needed component
            focusTest.setFocus();
            focusTest.setSelection(0, 0);

            // creates a new Timer
            var minuteTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000, 30);

            // designates listeners for the interval and completion events
            minuteTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTick);
            minuteTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, onTimerComplete);

            // starts the timer ticking
            minuteTimer.start();
        }    
        public function onTick(event:TimerEvent):void {
            // displays the tick count so far
            trace("tick " + event.target.currentCount);
            if (focusTest.getStyle('focusColor') != 0x008CEA) {
                focusTest.setStyle('focusColor', 0x008CEA);
            } else {
                focusTest.setStyle('focusColor', 0xFF0000);
            }
            //Update everything somehow :)            
        }    
        public function onTimerComplete(event:TimerEvent):void {
            trace("Time's Up!");
        }            
        ]]></mx:Script>
    <mx:TextInput id="focusTest"/>
</mx:Application>
```

**What do I have:** The timer is ticking. The property is changing (you can see that, e.g. while switching tabs in your browser .. just catch the right state, when the color is changed).

**What do I want:** How to make this focus to be redrawn without magic (I've tried all the methods, starting with "`validate`", I've tried calling `updateDisplayList()` on entire application, I've tried to call `styleChanged` ... aggrrh .. I'm out of ideas :)).

Any thoughts?

Any help, as usual, is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: If I had to guess "focusColor" isn't something implemented to redraw on the fly; so you either have to lose focus, and gain focus back (it sounds like that is what you're doing by switching browser tabs) or override updateDisplayList() to redraw the focus ring if it changes. You'll have to pour through framework code to figure out where/when/how the focus element is drawn.

Comment: Aww .. the pair 'focusTest.drawFocus(false); focusTest.drawFocus(true);' solved the problem .. I was just wondering is there any more clean solution? :)
P.S. Thank you for your help :) You're like Super-Flex-man .. the first where throubles are, and hitting in the right place *giggle*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `themeColor` and `focusTest.drawColor(true)` it works fine. You have to use drawFocus() for it to recolor, and I dont think focusColor is a Flex 3 setStyle attribute (only used in Flex 4).

Tricky to spot, because if you use incorrect setStyle/getStyle attributes Flex does not throw any errors, it just ignores them!

```
    if (focusTest.getStyle('themeColor') != 0x008CEA) {
        focusTest.setStyle('themeColor', 0x008CEA);
    } else {
       focusTest.setStyle('themeColor', 0xFF0000);
    } 
   focusTest.drawFocus(true);
```

Full Code:

```
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
                creationComplete="init()">
    <mx:Script><![CDATA[    
        private function init():void {
            //putting focus inside needed component
            focusTest.setFocus();
            focusTest.setSelection(0, 0);

            // creates a new Timer
            var minuteTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000, 30);

            // designates listeners for the interval and completion events
            minuteTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTick);
            minuteTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, onTimerComplete);

            // starts the timer ticking
            minuteTimer.start();
        }    
        public function onTick(event:TimerEvent):void {
            // displays the tick count so far
            // displays the tick count so far

            trace("tick " + event.target.currentCount);
            if (focusTest.getStyle('themeColor') != 0x008CEA) {
                focusTest.setStyle('themeColor', 0x008CEA);
            } else {
                focusTest.setStyle('themeColor', 0xFF0000);
            }

            focusTest.drawFocus(true);
            //Update everything somehow :)             
        }    
        public function onTimerComplete(event:TimerEvent):void {
            trace("Time's Up!");
        }            
    ]]></mx:Script>
    <mx:TextInput id="focusTest" width="222"/>
</mx:Application>
```

Comment: *Sight* couldn't get it to work .. it's not even updated if I switch a tab and go back. But anyway, thanks for a try :) Btw, I already saw someone recommended using 'themeColor' in a similar case, but I had some doubts .. it's changing a global color, what if something other is using it?

Comment: Hi. I put the full code that I used/tested above, and it works fine. Try it out, maybe there is some slight difference

Comment: That's weird, but it doesn't work here .. :( Fully your code .. I can see the trace, informing me about changes each second, but nothing changed visually in application.

Comment: Uhu .. the problem is found :) I'm using 4.1.

Comment: Hehe .. true) Upvoting this answer for 3.5 users :)